# Manage URLs on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm coding a WordPress template and I need to manage the WordPress URLs in a way that the first parameter should be only two character and can appear or not, without affecting the following parameters. For example: algo.com/{2-characters}/more-things or algo.com/more-things
When the first parameter does not appear, WordPress should assume the default value for that parameter (or variable).

I tried WordPress tutorials on URL rewrite but can't get it to work